# Circle image on hover occupy 100% height and width

Tags: css, reactjs

Hi I'm trying to do an animation on hover, without the hover I would like my circle to make 100% of the height and width

and for some reason I am not able to leave my circle with 100% border radius

like this:

[image]

code:

```
export const TeamCard = styled.div`
  background: red;
  padding: 10px 0;
  & .bgCircle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 64px;
    background: hotpink;
  }
`;
export default function App() {
  return (
    <TeamCard>
      <div className="bgCircle" />
      <div class="description">
        <h3>huhuehu</h3>
        <h3>testing</h3>
      </div>
    </TeamCard>
```

example:

> https://codesandbox.io/s/dry-river-09ft0

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you mean. But if your circle is 100% the height and width of a rectangular container, it will no longer be a circle. It would become oblong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the following styled-div:

```js
export const TeamCard = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  & .bgCircle {
    border-radius: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    background: hotpink;
    transition: all ease 333ms;
  }
  &:hover {
    .bgCircle {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      height: 300px;
      width: 300px;
      border-radius: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
    }
  }
  & .description {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
  }
`;
```

This is making use of absolute positioning to correctly set where the circle should go. In order to make absolute positioning work, the containing element needs to have a position of something other than 'static'.

The transition property is what provides the animation.